# Have a fixed outer container but an inner container stretching to fit floating divs that overflow outer container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an outer container (#container) of a fixed dimension, and an inner div (.inner) that might overflow the outer container and allow scrolling. In this inner div, I want list items that consists of two divs (.name and .rectangle) for which the second div appears to the right of the first div, and I want the inner div to stretch to fit the contents. I've tried clearfixes but they don't work (or maybe I'm using them wrongly) and position: absolute on the innermost divs don't stretch the parent div (.inner).

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jj4Tk/4/

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="first">This div should overflow</div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="name">This div should overflow too</div>
                        <div class="rectangle"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to make the red rectangle float, appearing to the right of the text, and have the enclosing div stretch to fit the two rectangles? The only I'm trying to achieve a "package-explorer" effect, so I'm going to have a list of directory/file names in a tree like structure. The rectangle would happen to be my menu icon (which appears on hover of the directory/file name).

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you floating the red rectangle to the left, if you want it on the right side …? I’m not really sure what you actually want, I can only guess it might be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jj4Tk/6/

Comment: hi please find updated fiddle link of the same http://jsfiddle.net/cooolkiran/jj4Tk/7/

Comment: Thanks both, that seemed to work on the fiddle. I'll try it out!

Comment: Unfortunately, the .wrap div doesn't seem to have the dimensions of its child elements. Is there a way to get that working?